# durandal activate function async code

Tags: javascript, durandal

I'm using Durandal 1.2, in my viewmodel i have function activate:

```
    self.activate = function (data) {
        function update(clienteId) {
            self.Loading(true);
            return $.when(
               clienteRepository.ClienteCompact(clienteId),
               clienteRepository.Prodotti(clienteId),
               clienteRepository.Interventi(clienteId),
               clienteRepository.Abbonamenti(clienteId)
               ).then(function (cliente, prodotti, interventi, abbonamenti) {
                   self.Cliente(cliente[0]).Prodotti(prodotti[0]).Interventi(interventi[0]).Abbonamenti(abbonamenti[0]);
                   self.Loading(false);
                   debugger;
               });
        };

        var clienteId = data.splat[1];
        if ($.isNumeric(clienteId)) {
            return update();
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

and i have function beforeBind:

```
    self.beforeBind = function () {
        debugger;
    };
```

the problem is that the function beforeBind is called before the ajax request ends so the view is empty.

there is something wrong?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just move your the code from your function inside of your then() statement.  The then() handles the returned promise from the Ajax.

Another option is to change your function from a constructor function to a standard function statement.  As is your function is evaluated before it is called.

Instead of

```
var myFunc = function () {};
```

Use

```
function myFunc () {}
```